# WPF: Can I show one double in two different ways?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am creating a "Progress-Bar-Clock", where the Time gets shown as percentages. For example, this is the time right now:

[image]

Xaml:

```
<Viewbox>
<Grid>
    <Grid.DataContext>
        <vm:TimerVM/>
    </Grid.DataContext>

    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,10,10,10">

        <Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1">
            <Label Content="Progress Bar Timer" FontFamily="Bold" FontSize="45" HorizontalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,20"/>
        </Border>
        <StackPanel>
            <Label Content="Seconds in this Minute:"/>
            <Grid Width="400" Height="25">
                <ProgressBar Value="{Binding SecondsInMinute}" />
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <Run Text="{Binding SecondsInMinute}"/><Run Text="%"/>
                </TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel>
            <Label Content="Minutes in this hour:"/>
            <Grid Width="400" Height="25">
                <ProgressBar Value="{Binding MinutesInHour}" />
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <Run Text="{Binding MinutesInHour}"/><Run Text="%"/>
                </TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel>
            <Label Content="Hours in this day:"/>
            <Grid Width="400" Height="25">
                <ProgressBar Value="{Binding HoursInDay}" />
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <Run Text="{Binding HoursInDay}"/><Run Text="%"/>
                </TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Margin="0,50,0,0">
            <Label Content="Time until timer finished:"/>
            <Grid Width="400" Height="25">
                <ProgressBar Value="{Binding TimerInPercent}" />
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <Run Text="{Binding TimerInPercent}"/><Run Text="%"/>
                </TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

The thing that disturbs me is the percentage. At the moment I show it with only two digits, so it's easier to read, but that also affects the progress bar.

This is the method, my second thread executes to update the timer:

```
private void UpdateRelative()
{
    while (true)
    {
        DateTime time = DateTime.Now;

        SecondsInMinute = Math.Round(time.Second / 0.6);
        MinutesInHour = Math.Round(time.Minute / 0.6);
        HoursInDay = Math.Round(time.Hour / 0.24);

        Thread.Sleep(timeout);
    }
}
```

I would like to use a non-rounded up number for the progress bar, but a rounded one for the text on the progress bar. Is that possible without creating a second property that the label would use?

Comment: How about creating a FloorConverter for the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could format the displayed value in the view instead of rounding the actual value:

```
<Run Text="{Binding MinutesInHour, StringFormat=N0}"/><Run Text="%"/>
```

Code:

```
MinutesInHour = time.Minute / 0.6;
```